# PGFPlot two \pgfplotstableregressiona

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Hi i have two plot with two linear regression but the legend show the same equation for the straight line... I haven't made a MWE because I thought it isn't needed---Is it?

```
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
97 1.0
96 15
96 29.2
96 32
98 42.4
98 59.2
98 66.1
97 84.4
100 94.0
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slopeA{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\interceptA{\pgfplotstableregressionb}



\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableB

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableB}

\xdef\slopeB{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\interceptB{\pgfplotstableregressionb}
```

and in every plot i put this for make a the legend...

```
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
```

This one of my plot...

```
\addplot [%
    point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
    mark=*,
    draw=none, forget plot]table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,mesh line legend,point meta=x,domain=95.2:99.8,very thick,samples=1000] {\slopeA*x+\interceptA};
```

Comment: You should use `\slopeA` and `\slopeB` in your legend: That's why you used the `\xdef` assignment, so you'd be able to refer to the parameters later on.

Comment: Is a MWE needed? Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THANKS JAKE

```
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\slopeB} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\interceptB}$}
```