# pgfplots two linear regressions

Tags: pgfplotstable

There are many existing questions about using the pgfplots linear regression.

You can imagine using code such as:

```
\addplot table [draw = none, dash pattern=on, x=x_data, y={create col/linear regression={y=y_data}}, col sep=comma] {data.dat};
\addlegendentry{line A $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona}$}
```

But suppose you have two linear regressions, how do you get both values of `\pgfplotstableregressiona` ?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After posting I now see that this question was infact asked and answered within:

[PGFPlot two \pgfplotstableregressiona](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60749/pgfplot-two-pgfplotstableregressiona?rq=1)